# Why can't I update on Windows my old Bluetooth driver dating from 2006

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

I updated all the drivers on my machine, but I went to check the bluetooth driver version and it was one from the year 2006 (*Driver provider: Microsoft; Driver date: **21/06/2006**; Driver version: 10.0.18362.1*).
I tried to update via WinUpdate but it says that this is already the latest version. But why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your Bluetooth driver is not actually old, it's current, what problem related to the driver are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to connect a bluetooth joystick, but it's not responding to commands. I thought it was a problem with the Windows driver, but apparently it is not.

Answer (score 4):

It's worse than you think - read the article
[Why are all Windows drivers dated June 21, 2006?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170208-00/?p=95395)

> The dates on **all Windows drivers are set to June 21, 2006**. The version number increases over time, but the timestamp stays put.

The reason for this backdating is simple : Microsoft doesn't want
every time that it compiles a new version of a driver, for it
to take priority over drivers provided by the manufacturer because
it has a newer date.

If the drivers by Microsoft were not backdated to antiquity, sooner or
later all your drivers would be replaced by Microsoft's generic
drivers.

In other words, the drivers by Microsoft are chosen as the last
option, and only if no other driver exists for the device,
because they seem to be old drivers, and this is by design.

Comment: Great answer. That helped me also, that is a question I have had for quite a while. Thank you HarryMC, it explained a lot